# PDF reader with a sliding ruler overlay to keep track of current line

Tags: pdf-viewer

I'm looking for a PDF reader version of this clipboard:

[image: clipboard with ruler]

I don't need OCR, text-to-speech, or any fancy features, just a simple digital sliding ruler overlay to keep track of the current line.

Is there a free or low-cost PDF reader (Windows, Mac, or iPad) or add-on that does this?

Answer (score 0):

A Ruler for Windows ( https://arulerforwindows.com ) has a feature that allows you to used it as a Reading Guide, basically exactly what you are looking for I think.  Its free too. I wrote it.

Comment: While this is not spam, you should probably read the help on self promotion.

Comment: Thank you.  Following your suggestion, I just did.  For others that are interested it is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion